# HTML editable <td> using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

so im doing that editable table thingy and I found a good example to start through but I have faced some problems.

```
<td contenteditable="true" class="hover" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'question','1')" onClick="showEdit(this);">Blab Bla 1</td>
```

Okay so thats is my echo'ed line by the database and in the onBlur= there is the id which is 1 so I can easily save it on blur, and on click I edit the td.

So instead of bluring to save the database I wanted to make it onkeypress(enter)=SaveToDatabase but then I thought that how is that possible since the database echo's it as inline javascript so i need to find a way to make it onkeypress (13 ~ enter) it save to database..

Comment: What do `showEdit ()` do? What it could do is wrap the content of the <td> in a form so that the user can just press enter and the form will be submitted, and you can handle whatever you want to do with Javascript by capturing the form's submit event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

HTML

```
onkeypress="if(checkIfEnter(event)){saveToDatabase(this,'question','1')}"    
//or
onkeypress="if(checkIfEnter(event)){this.blur();}"
```

JS

```
function checkIfEnter(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.keyCode != 13) {return false};
  e.preventDefault();
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Works perfect but the problem is when I press Enter, a new line begins and I need it to remove focusing or remove selecting the td

Comment: @MoemenWalid Try `onkeypress="if(checkIfEnter(event)){this.blur();}"`, it should fire the blur event, which will save to database

Comment: Fixed after adding e.preventdefault() if key enter is true

`function checkIfEnter(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode != 13) {return false};
    e.preventDefault();
    return true;
  }`

with `onkeypress="if(checkIfEnter(event)){this.blur();}"`

Comment: Thanks alot for the help,